# Java Guava: Iterating and removing keys of Multimap

Tags: java, loops, guava, multimap

I'm trying to iterate over a Multimap and remove some keys and their values based on a arbitrary check.

```
Multimap<Integer, Character> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

myMultimap.keySet().stream().forEach((bin) -> {
    if (random.nextDouble() < p) {
        myMultimap.removeAll(bin);
    }
});
```

This obviously throws a ConcurrentModificationException.

So I tried:

```
Iterator<Integer> i = myMultimap.keySet().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if (random.nextDouble() < p) {
        i.remove();         
    }
}
```

This however results in a java.lang.IllegalStateException: no calls to next() since the last call to remove().
I've tried to play around with it like the code below, but I still get the same error after a couple of iterations.

```
Iterator<Integer> i = myMultimap.keySet().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if (random.nextDouble() < p) {
        i.remove();
        i.next();
    } else {
        i.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the iterator is created, it points **before** the first element. You have to call `next()` before you can call `remove()` to advance the iterator (even though you don't need the element). [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) will affect the element which has been returned by the call to `next()`.

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate over the map and save all keys to remove in a list.

```
Iterator<Integer> i = myMultimap.keySet().iterator();
List<Integer> keyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    if (random.nextDouble() < p)
        keyList.add(i);
}
```

and then remove every entry of the list from the map:

```
for (Integer key : keyList)
    myMultimap.remove(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Michael Koch said, `next()` needs to be called before `remove()`. The following code should work.

```
Iterator<Integer> i = myMultimap.keySet().iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    i.next();
    if (random.nextDouble() < p) { 
        i.remove();
    } 
}
```